# Troubleshooting a DHCP server (gets an APIPA address)

Tags: ip, dhcp

I have a very limited knowledge of networks but am still expected to fix this problem.

A retail store has various devices on their DHCP server; cameras, TVs, etc. (Honestly, I really don't know anything about DHCP except that it is used to pick out available IP addresses for devices instead of using static ones).
Recently the TVs stopped working (the streaming of video stopped) and the company that services the TV streaming tells me it is a DHCP problem.

At a similar time, I noticed that some of the cameras were getting different port numbers than they had before and now recently a few of them have become inaccessible (not sure if this is related).
I read somewhere that this may be an issue with not having enough IP addresses for all our devices (with the many devices we have, I wouldn't be surprised). But I have no idea how to check how many we have and how many are in use. And if that's the problem, I don't know how to fix it.

And if that is not the problem, I have no idea how to proceed.
Any ideas?

**Edit**

I have access to a computer on the network via Teamviewer but that's about it. I'm not sure how DHCP is set up, but I know it's related to the router, and I have access to it through that computer. In the router admin, I can now see that there are only 40ish IPs leased, while the start IP if 192.168.1.10 and the end IP is 192.168.1.100, so there should be some remaining IPs. On the router there are a few tests: (check for more dhcp servers, test fo IP address conflicts) but they show no problems.

I have now received more information from the TV streaming provider: "the media player is unable to reach the DHCP and gets an APIPA address instead".
Perhaps that adds more clarity.

Comment: If the router is acting as the DHCP server then as a first step reboot the router.

Comment: @joeqwerty I will be very happy at the same time as I will feel very silly if that fixes the problem. But I'll have to get someone on-site to try that. :)

Comment: Does the router not have a reboot/restart option in the admin console?

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm afraid it didn't help to restart. Is there a way for me to check if DHCP gives me an IP to see if it is a fault with the device itself?

Comment: OK, now I wonder how the TV streaming provider can tell the status of the TV's network configuration if the TV can't access the network! Now I suspect that either the TV is on the network and talking to the Internet, or the provider is feeding you a bunch of crap. Or both. Either way I suspect this will require a site visit to check the physical cabling and possibly the TV's network configuration.